# Difference by executing SQL in SQLOLEDB and MSDASQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-connection, oledb

I have an problem with the following SQL String:

```
DECLARE @s varchar(1000), @ver nvarchar(128)
SET @ver = Server Version (e.g. 11 for SQL Server 2012)
SELECT @s = case
WHEN
(CheckVersion (e.g. Enterprise)) AND @ver > 9
THEN
'BACKUP DATABASE [DB] TO DISK = ''C:\Backup\DBBackup.bak'' WITH  COMPRESSION, NOFORMAT, NOINIT, SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10'
ELSE
'BACKUP DATABASE [DB] TO DISK = ''C:\Backup\DBBackup.bak'' WITH  NOFORMAT, NOINIT, SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10;'
END
EXEC (@s)
```

(This is the short Version, i know that this don't work)

When im using SQLOLEDB Provider everything works fine and the Backupfiles getting created.

The same Command in MSDASQL don't crash, but even create no Backupfile.

Could someone explain, why the same command works with SQLOLEDB and not with MSDASQL? 
What is the specific different between these two Providers?

Comment: Could you try `EXEC('SELECT 1')` using both providers and share result?

Comment: Second share how you call/execute this script.

Comment: Using an OLEDB vs ODBC provider does *not* affect how the server executes a script that doesn't even have parameters. How *do* you execute the script? What language are you using? Are you targeting the same server in both cases?  *How* do you determine the server version? How do you know there are no errors since you don't check the return status of `EXEC`?

Comment: I'm using VB6 my SQL Script fills @ver with the Server Version (number).  "CheckVersion" return the Server "Name" (e.g. Enterprise). Would the Script fail my VB6 function would return false and the error message, but nothing happens.

Comment: When i'm using SQLOLEDB everything works fine. With MSDASQL no backup gets created. When i'm only using the Backup script (`BACKUP DATABASE [DB] TO DISK = 'C:\Backup\DBBackup.bak' WITH  NOFORMAT, NOINIT, SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10;`) it works. Why not with the WHEN Statement?

Comment: @lad2025 With both Providers the result is 1

Comment: just a wild guess, maybe you are messing with the literals when using the second method (I assume you got 2 methods, one for each drive). Search for a unclosed quotation at the second. Also if you are unsing the same server try just to run a profile to check what the SQL engine is actually receiving from your app

Comment: The Profiler Shows the same result.  I'd copied the recieved Command and executed it in SSMS. It worked and the Profiler shows the same result. But i got only the Backup from SSMS, not VB6 with MSDASQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got fixed the Problem.

OLEDB via ADO has always had the issue where DONE_IN_PROC messages (rows affected) confuse code that is not expecting them. A workaround without app code changes is to specify SET NOCOUNT ON as the first statement in the Batch.